# Matrices and bases

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functions, proof-verification

[image]

Can you please verify my argument:

Let $M = \begin{pmatrix} a & b\\ c& d\end{pmatrix}$, where $a,b,c,d$ are all real.

$$AM=\begin{pmatrix} c & d\\ a& b\end{pmatrix}$$

Let $B$ be the basis of $V, B=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0\\ 0& 1\end{pmatrix}$

$$f=\begin{pmatrix} c & d\\ a& b\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: That can't possibly be true since $\;\dim_{\Bbb R}V=4\;$ and thus the matrix corresponding to an operator on this space has to be $\;4\times 4\;$...and of course $\;B\;$ is not a basis of $\;V\;$ .

Comment: @Timbuc thanks for your reply, can you be clearer with how I can rectify this?

Answer (score 0):

First, $\;\dim V=4\;$ so we're looking for $\;4\;$ linearly independent vectors in $\;V\;$ . The "usual", or more commonly basis, is

$$B:=\left\{\;v_1:=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}\,,\,\,v_2:=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}\,,\,\,v_3:=\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\1&0\end{pmatrix}\,,\,\,v_4:=\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}\;\right\}$$

It's easy to check $\;B\;$ is actually a basis of $\;V\;$ , and now we can calculate the matrix of $\;f\;$ wrt it:

$$\begin{align*}fv_1=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\1&0\end{pmatrix}=0\cdot v_1+0\cdot v_2+1\cdot v_3+0\cdot v_4\\{}\\
fv_2=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}=0\cdot v_1+0\cdot v_2+0\cdot v_3+1\cdot v_4\\{}\\
fv_3=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\1&0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}=1\cdot v_1+0\cdot v_2+0\cdot v_3+0\cdot v_4\\{}\\
fv_4=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}=0\cdot v_1+1\cdot v_2+0\cdot v_3+0\cdot v_4\end{align*}$$

Thus, the matrix representation of $\;f\;$ wrt $\;B\;$ is

$$[f]_B=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&1\\
1&0&0&0\\
0&1&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$